# GWT and autofill

Tags: html, gwt, autocomplete, autofill

I've noticed that browsers don't recognize my password field as a potential auto-complete target.  I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that the password field isn't in the original HTML - it's created by my GWT script after the page has loaded.

Is there a way to tell a browser, "hey, here's this form, treat it like usual?"  How can I let browsers hook into my app for autofill?

Comment: I create a user script that solve that annoying problem. That works for Gerrit login form, but should work on all GWT based projects https://github.com/mems/gerrit-autofill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some workarounds to get the browser to auto-complete your login like the one described [here](http://borglin.net/gwt-project/?page_id=467).

After struggling some time with it I strongly suggest you simply wrap an existing form of your host page (do not generate the inputs with GWT), do a `form.submit()` on it and have a servlet listen to the request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that password fields ( tags with type="password") are not auto-filled for fairly obvious security reasons. It doesn't matter that the field is added after page load by your GWT script.

Try mimicking the field in regular HTML and compare that to how your GWT app creates the DOM structure. Perhaps your GWT app is putting the page together differently?

Comment: What I really want is for browsers to offer to remember users' username/password combinations.  The DOM structure is pretty simple - two <input> elements, one with type="password", each in its own div but those divs right next to each other.  What else do browsers need?  The submit mechanism is not an <input type="submit"/> or but a gwt-rpc call... maybe that's it?